# Can't connect to Mysql installation on Centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos

Install MySQL using `mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm`

started the MySQL server using `service mysqld start`

when I try to connect MySQL or any other client app on the localhost I get.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I never set an admin password not sure what is the default and what am I missing.

Comment: Have you run `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` yet?

Comment: I did following is the output
[needanapp@needanapp ~]$ sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to reset the password,in some cases theres no need to enter any password simply press Enter when prompted and then you can change the password using ALTER USER command,but if it doesn't works Go through the following procedure,

First you will have to get the temporary password , type in the terminal :

```
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

You will get a temporary password at the end of the sentence, login to mysql using that temporary password as

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter Password : (Enter you Temporary password Here)
```

Now you will have to change the default password, for that you will have to go through some rules.
**NOTE: Type the following command inside mysql**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

You will get a table like :

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 8      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

For minimal validation, type(optional you can change it anytime)

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_length=6;
mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;
```

This will check for minimum 6 digit password

Now you can change the default password,

For E.g if you want to set 123456 as your new password

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/messages for more details.

Comment: All good. I can see server started and running. Have also checked the status, all good.